# Flipping one digit to get all digits the same: is the code wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to solve the following problem:

Given a binary D containing only digits 0's and 1's, I have to determine if all the digits could be made the same, by flipping only one digit.

The input is the number of Ds to test, and then the Ds, one per line. for instance:

```
3
11111001111010
110
100000000000000
```

The output is "Yes" or "No", namely in this instance, the run will look like:

```
$ python3 first.py
3
11111001111010
NO
110
YES
100000000000000
YES
```

However, the automatic evaluator of this problem judges the following code wrong:

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    line = input()
    ones = zeros = 0
    for c in line:
        if int(c) == 1:
            ones += 1
        elif int(c) == 0:
            zeros += 1
        else:
            raise ValueError
        if ones > 1 and zeros > 1:
            print("NO")
            break

    if ones == 1:
        print("YES")
    elif zeros == 1:
        print("YES")
```

Can you suggest why?

Comment: the `if ones > 1 ...` is wrongly indented

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: No it isn't.  As soon as we have seen 2 ones and 2 zeros we can stop looking at additional digits.

Comment: @boardrider actually your code does return what it is supposed to. for which case is it not behaving as intended?

Comment: That's the thing, @Ev: the checker robot just rejects the code, but does not show what is wrong. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather embarrassing: I outputted the answer as all *uppercase*, where the expected output is *Title case*. The following code is accepted:

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    line = input()
    ones = zeros = 0
    for c in line:
        if int(c) == 1:
            ones += 1
        elif int(c) == 0:
            zeros += 1
        else:
            raise ValueError
        if ones > 1 and zeros > 1:
            print("No")
            break

    if ones == 1:
        print("Yes")
    elif zeros == 1:
        print("Yes")
    elif ones == 0 or zeros == 0:
        print("No")
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution, I was just adding a comment asking about the correct case.

Comment: It was your one-but-last comment, @niemmi - that made me realise I was outputting the wrong case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't output anything in case that all the digits are the same. You can fix the problem by changing the last part in following way:

```
if ones == 1:
    print("YES")
elif zeros == 1:
    print("YES")
elif ones == 0 or zeros == 0:
    print("NO") # assuming that one bit must be changed
```

Note that you could just use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to count zeros (or ones) and then check if count is `1` or `len(line) - 1`:

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    line = input()
    zeros = line.count('0')
    print('YES' if zeros == 1 or zeros == len(line) - 1 else 'NO')
```

Comment: I would suggest *not* printing "NO" when we see multiple zeros and ones (but do break), and then just writing `if ones == 1 || zeros == 1: print("YES"); else: print("NO")`

Comment: @MartinBonner True, I just presented the fix that would require minimum amount of changes to original code. Of course the problem has much simpler solutions of which I've added one to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @niemmi for pointing to these edge cases. Alas, even with that fix, the checker robot still rejects my code.

Comment: @boardrider: Do you know if you **have to** flip a bit or is it optional? What is the expected output in case the input is `000`?

Comment: One bit _has_ to be flipped, @niemmi. The expected output is `No.`